# IIS from IP address does not function, from localhost it runs normal

Tags: iis-7

I have a web site in IIS 7.0, from the navigator I write

```
http:// localhost /
```

and the server responses the expected web content, however, when I write

```
http://192.168.#.##
```

(`localhost` is the same `192.168.#.##`), the server responses the following error:

**MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS**
ModuleName ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification 16
HttpStatus 404
HttpReason Not Found
HttpSubStatus 0
ErrorCode 0
ConfigExceptionInfo
Notification MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER
ErrorCode The operation completed successfully. (0x0)


**MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS**
ModuleName IIS Web Core 
Notification 16 
HttpStatus 404 
HttpReason Not Found
 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 2147942402 
ConfigExceptionInfo  
Notification MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER 
ErrorCode The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)

Comment: What OS? Is this full fat IIS7 or IIS7.5 Express?

Comment: Windows 2008 Server Enterprise IIS 7.0

Comment: In addition, when I write the IP, the navigator shows http error 404.